# selenium not detecting a link in firefox but same test runs fine in internet explorer

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, testng, junit4

My selenium tests are working fine on internet explorer but they are not able to recognize some of the links in firefox, even when I am using their ids to detect them.
Any solution will be much appreciated.

thanks,
Nitin

Comment: You might want to post an example so people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with xpath or CSS and let me know it's working or not..

Answer (score 0):

Try using different selectors. [CSS](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/) is proven to be more browser-independent.